# button onclick function firing twice

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have a button that calls a javascript function using an event handler. For some reason, the event handler is being called twice.

Here is my button (I am using a php object to generate the code, that's why there are a lot of empty tags):

```
<button name="addToCart" value="" size="" onclick="" src="" class="addToCartButton" id="0011110421111" type="button" formtarget="_self" formmethod="post" formaction="" data-mini="true" width="" height="" placeholder="" data-mini="1" onkeypress="" >Add To Cart</button>
```

Here is my event handler:

```
$('.addToCartButton').click(function() {
    alert("bob");
    //addToCart($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Here, I am getting the alert twice.

I have tried calling the function addToCart in the button's onclick property, but if I try it that way, I get this error:

```
TypeError: '[object HTMLButtonElement]' is not a function (evaluating 'addToCart(0011110421111)')
```

I have also tried event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation(), and neither worked.

Any ideas why this is happening, or what I can do to stop it from executing twice, or maybe why I am getting an error if I call the javascript function from onclick=""?

Comment: You are probably calling that code that assigns the event twice!

Comment: Why do you have so many blank attributes?

Comment: Do you have an onsubmit function as well somewhere?

Comment: @tymeJV I am using an object that creates the button tag and just passes in values that are set.

Comment: @David Nguyen  No, there is no onsubmit function for this button

Comment: What does `$._data( $(".addToCartButton")[0], "events" ).length` tell you? It should return the number of events bound to the button.

Comment: @matewka How would I use that? Do I put that in an alert inside the event handler? If so, it returned undefined, so I'm guessing that's not right.

Comment: My mistake. Do it that way: Open Chrome browser, go to your website, hit F12, click the `console` tab and paste this: `$._data( $(".addToCartButton")[0], "events")`. An object containing all events bound to your button will be printed to the console. The `click` property should be an array with more than one element. Expand each of them and right click on handler function. choose "Show function definition" and you should see where every handler is defined in your code. That way you should find your duplicate.

Comment: Ok, the click property has 2 elements.  Both, are from the handler I have posted in my initial question above.  The first one is located in the file that the function above exists (home.php).  The second exists in a file that I did not create (VM237).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click events firing multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Maybe you are attaching the event twice on the same button. What you could do is unbind any previously set click events like this:

```
$('.addToCartButton').unbind('click').click(function() {
    alert("bob");
    //addToCart($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This works for all attached events (mouseover, mouseout, click, ...)

Comment: .off().on() is likely more current

Comment: Since this answer probably works I won't `-1` it. But I strongly discourage fixing things by _undoing_ them rather than finding the real problem and removing it.

Comment: @matewka: thanks for the suggestion, worthwhile remainder. It saved me from messing up my code. Imho, the answer did not deserve a -1 also because it points to a not-so-obvious issue that many might do: setting an event listener twice on the same object.

Answer (score 17):

My event was firing twice because I accidentally included both my_scripts.js AND my_scripts.min.js. Ensure you only include one.

Answer (score 8):

Unbind event from selector and after appending in element in DOM again trigger event on specific selector..
$("selector_name").unbind( "event" ); //After this call event on selector again..

For example:

```
$( "#button" ).unbind( "click" );

$("#button").click(function(event) {
console.log("button click again);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Just for the record in case someone else's having the same problem, I had the same issue, the root cause was that there were 3 buttons with the same ID, after clicking one, the other two also fired their OnClick events...

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to pass in the event and add

```
$('.addToCartButton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Added this
  alert("bob");
  //addToCart($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

OR

```
$('.addToCartButton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Added this
  alert("bob");
  //addToCart($(this).attr("id"));
  return false;
});
```

Comment: OP said it didn't help.

Comment: OP said the preventDefault, he didnt say anything about returning false.

Comment: Anyway, `preventDefault` is not a property but a function.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I found out my events were not bound to my mapped component. The relevant answer is at [Why is my onClick being called on render? - React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226076/why-is-my-onclick-being-called-on-render-react-js) but to provide some insights I've copied some of the answer below (Hope this helps!):

**1.** using .bind

```
activatePlaylist.bind(this, playlist.playlist_id)
```

**2.** using arrow function

```
onClick={ () => this.activatePlaylist(playlist.playlist_id) }
```

**3.** or return function from activatePlaylist

```
activatePlaylist(playlistId) {
  return function () {
     // you code 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my MVC project, and the problem was that I had included site.js twice; once in the _Layout.cshtml file and once in the Scripts section of the main cshtml file. Removing one solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of error:

- It may be that you have duplicate events bound
- Either the event handler could be hooked up twice, *or* maybe the event *isn't being unbound*, after the intended listener(s) have finished listening and have done their job.

In this case, you need to do something to *unbind* the listener once you no longer need to listen.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for answers.  It turned out that mine wasn't exactly firing twice.  It would fire, then when I later clicked something else, it would also fire for that click.

I had a container div with a click listener on it.
Inside that div, a clickable link.

Clicking the link also fired the container's click event.

I spent some time with unbind('click') / rebind experiments but nothing was satisfactory.  In the end I simply put a condition in the container click event so that it only ran if the click target wasn't an anchor: -

```
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'A') {    
        alert("bob");
        //addToCart($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

My mistake was having a parent have the same class name as the child that i had attached the click event handler to. This caused me some confusion.