# Why is my onClick being called on render? - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that I have created:

```
class Create extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var playlistDOM = this.renderPlaylists(this.props.playlists);
    return (
      <div>
        {playlistDOM}
      </div>
    )
  }

  activatePlaylist(playlistId) {
    debugger;
  }

  renderPlaylists(playlists) {
    return playlists.map(playlist => {
      return <div key={playlist.playlist_id} onClick={this.activatePlaylist(playlist.playlist_id)}>{playlist.playlist_name}</div>
    });
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    playlists: state.playlists
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Create);
```

When I `render` this page, `activatePlaylist` is called for each `playlist` in my `map`.  If I `bind` `activatePlaylist` like:

```
activatePlaylist.bind(this, playlist.playlist_id)
```

I can also use an anonymous function:

```
onClick={() => this.activatePlaylist(playlist.playlist_id)}
```

then it works as expected.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

You need pass to `onClick` **reference** to function, when you do like this `activatePlaylist( .. )` you call function and pass to `onClick` value that returned from `activatePlaylist`. You can use one of these three options:

**1**. using `.bind`

```
activatePlaylist.bind(this, playlist.playlist_id)
```

**2**. using arrow function

```
onClick={ () => this.activatePlaylist(playlist.playlist_id) }
```

**3**. or return function from `activatePlaylist`

```
activatePlaylist(playlistId) {
  return function () {
     // you code 
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't remember it working in previous versions of `React` this way.  Am I remembering wrong or has the `api` changed?

Comment: @jhamm You are using ES6 classes and in this case you should bind context manually.

Comment: @AlexanderT. there is one thing that I don't get it. If you bind the context with `.bind`, as you say in step 1, it's necessary to do step 2? and if it is, why? Because I think that when you use arrow function, the context is the one that it is where the function was defined, but if we are attaching the context using `.bind`, the context is already attached, right?

Comment: @Rafa Romero it is just three different options, you can use one of them

Comment: @AlexanderT. OK! it was what I though. Then, I don understand what is going wrong in my case, because I'm binding the context to the method with the `.bind`, and sending the method down to a component using props. Then, in the component, If I call it like this: `onClick={props.myMethod()`, the method it's called automatically without doing anything and infinite times. Only works fine if I call the method using flat arrow, so in that case is not necessary to bind the context with `.bind`

Comment: There's now a section on the official React Docs website answered this question in full depth: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: If you're having issues with these three options, something like this worked for me: 
`activatePlaylist = (playlistId) => () => { your code
}`

Comment: it helps... worlded for me

Comment: there's a 4th way - declare your function like so:
  `const activatePlaylist= (value) => () =>{`

Answer (score 22):

I know this post is a few years old already, but just to reference the latest React tutorial/documentation about this common mistake (I made it too) from https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html:

> Note
>
> To save typing and avoid the confusing behavior of this, we will use
>   the arrow function syntax for event handlers here and further below:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <button className="square" onClick={() => alert('click')}>
       {this.props.value}
     </button>
   );
 }
}
```

> Notice how with onClick={() => alert('click')}, we’re passing a
>   function as the onClick prop. React will only call this function after
>   a click. Forgetting () => and writing onClick={alert('click')} is a
>   common mistake, and would fire the alert every time the component
>   re-renders.

Comment: I had an arrow function in front of it like this, and it was still activating.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour was documented when React announced the release of class based components.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html

> **Autobinding**
>
> React.createClass has a built-in magic feature that bound all methods to this automatically for you. This can be a little confusing for JavaScript developers that are not used to this feature in other classes, or it can be confusing when they move from React to other classes.
>
> Therefore we decided not to have this built-in into React's class model. You can still explicitly prebind methods in your constructor if you want.

Answer (score 3):

The way you passing the method `this.activatePlaylist(playlist.playlist_id)`, will call the method immediately. You should pass the reference of the method to the `onClick` event. Follow one of the below-mentioned implementation to resolve your problem.

1.

```
onClick={this.activatePlaylist.bind(this,playlist.playlist_id)}
```

Here bind property is used to create a reference of the `this.activatePlaylist` method by passing `this` context and argument `playlist.playlist_id`

2.

```
onClick={ (event) => { this.activatePlaylist.(playlist.playlist_id)}}
```

This will attach a function to the onClick event which will get triggered on user click action only. When this code exectues the `this.activatePlaylist` method will be called.

Answer (score 3):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Page ,Navbar, Popup} from 'framework7-react';

class AssignmentDashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {

    }

    
      onSelectList=(ProjectId)=>{
          return(

            console.log(ProjectId,"projectid")
          )

      }
            
render() {
       
    return (   
      
 <li key={index} onClick={()=> this.onSelectList(item.ProjectId)}></li>
                       
                       )}
```

Comment: Could you add a little bit of explanation instead of just posting bits of code? It would really improve the quality of your answer