# onClick property fired when component is rendered react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi I am building a frontend in react and I am rendering a List of places that I get from google maps api. I want each place to fire an action on onClick. If I don't pass any value it works, if I pass the id of the place that I get from props than onClick is fired when the list item is rendered leading to an error.
Here is the list component

```
import {ListGroup} from "react-bootstrap";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {selectedPlace} from "../../actions/searchActions";

const PlaceList=function (props) {
    const dispatch=useDispatch()

    const handleClick=function (id) {
        console.log('ciao '+id)
    }
    return(
        <ListGroup>
        {props.places.map(item=>{
            return (<ListGroup.Item variant="flush" onClick={handleClick(item['place_id'])}>{item['formatted_address']}</ListGroup.Item>)
        })}
        </ListGroup>
    )
}

export default PlaceList
```

I want the onClick to be fired just when the list item is clicked. Any Idea on how to solve?

Comment: As with the many duplicates, don’t call the function at binding. The binding site should evaluate to a function, and this returned function is the callback. Having the handleClick (call it handleClickCreator) return a closure is one method, as is creating a simple wrapping lambda. Behavior is discussed in https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34226076/2864740

Answer (score 0):

onClick functions should be called like this!

```
import { ListGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { selectedPlace } from "../../actions/searchActions";

const PlaceList = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log('ciao ' + id)
  }
  return (
    <ListGroup>
      {
        props.places.map(item => {
          return (<ListGroup.Item variant="flush" onClick={() => handleClick(item['place_id'])}>{item['formatted_address']}</ListGroup.Item>)
        })
      }
    </ListGroup>
  )
}

export default PlaceList
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. It's not recommended to use arrow functions within JSX.

Comment: @kinduser squse mi? What would be the problem doing so?

Comment: @AngelZlatanov performance downsides.

Comment: @kinduser haven't seen any with 2000 rendered items mapped from array with a 500 lines of not so complex functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick should be calling the function like this:

```
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { selectedPlace } from '../../actions/searchActions';

export default (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log('ciao ' + id);
  };

  return (
    <ListGroup>
      {props.places.map((item) => (
        <ListGroup.Item variant="flush" onClick={() => handleClick(item['place_id'])}>
          {item['formatted_address']}
        </ListGroup.Item>
      ))}
    </ListGroup>
  );
};
```

Comment: He wants an answer without arrow functions it seems! @Angel Zlatanov

Comment: @Veno then he should have specified that. Also in a hook makes no difference but w/e.

Comment: Yes, but he will not use arrow functions, so he can possibly use class and bind to this on constructor?

Comment: We are not oracles, he should be more specific on what he intends to do.

Comment: Yes exactly....