# the function connected to the button is called without pressing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, frontend, jsx

I have a React-JS code:

```js
class SideMenu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          inputNumber: '',
          inputMessage: ''
        };

        this.getAccountInfo = this.getAccountInfo.bind(this)
      }

    getAccountInfo(props) {
        console.log(props.inputNumber, props.inputMessage)
      }; 
      

    render() {

        return(
            <body className='SideMenuBg'>
                <div className='SideMenu'>
                    <frame className='sideMenuBackgroundFrame'>
                        <input type='text' value={this.state.inputNumber} onChange={evt => this.updateInputNumber(evt)} placeholder='Number'/>
                        <input type='text' value={this.state.inputMessage} onChange={evt => this.updateInputMessage(evt)} placeholder='Message'/>
                        <button onClick={this.getAccountInfo(this.state)}>press me</button>
                    </frame>
                </div>
            </body>
        )
    }

    updateInputNumber(evt) {
        const val = evt.target.value;   
        this.setState({
          inputNumber: val
        });
    }
    updateInputMessage(evt) {
        const val = evt.target.value;   
        this.setState({
          inputMessage: val
        });
    }
```

From this code, I expect that it will receive 2 values from my inputs and output them to the console ONLY after clicking the button. But instead, for some reason, my code launches the `getAccountInfo` function twice after any change in the values of my inputs. Moreover, when the button is pressed, the function is not invoked at all.

Comment: put the `getAccountInfo()` inside an anonymous function, Eg: `<button onClick={()=>this.getAccountInfo(this.state)}>press me</button>`

Comment: Just look at the difference between the way you bind the `onChange` events and the way you bound the `onClick`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my onClick being called on render? - React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226076/why-is-my-onclick-being-called-on-render-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking the function `getAccountInfo()` (with brackets) when passing it to `onClick`. You should just pass it without the brackets. To access the state value, you don't need to pass them as arguments. Just read `this.state` in the function body. See modified code

```
class SideMenu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          inputNumber: '',
          inputMessage: ''
        };

        this.getAccountInfo = this.getAccountInfo.bind(this)
      }

    getAccountInfo() {
        console.log(this.state.inputNumber, this.state.inputMessage)
      }; 
      

    render() {

        return(
            <body className='SideMenuBg'>
                <div className='SideMenu'>
                    <frame className='sideMenuBackgroundFrame'>
                        <input type='text' value={this.state.inputNumber} onChange={this.updateInputNumber} placeholder='Number'/>
                        <input type='text' value={this.state.inputMessage} onChange={this.updateInputMessage} placeholder='Message'/>
                        <button onClick={this.getAccountInfo}>press me</button>
                    </frame>
                </div>
            </body>
        )
    }

    updateInputNumber(evt) {
        const val = evt.target.value;   
        this.setState({
          inputNumber: val
        });
    }
    updateInputMessage(evt) {
        const val = evt.target.value;   
        this.setState({
          inputMessage: val
        });
    }
```