# Function runs despite not being called React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have two components below, both with callable functions. For some reason, upon clicking on the component `LineItem`, the function `navigateToURL` in `Header` is called, and I'm not sure why. Not only that, but the function `setSelected` doesn't run. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import "../style/entries.css";

function LineItem({ date, time, id, selected, setSelected }) {
    var classes = "list-item flex row";
    if (selected == id) classes += " selected";

    return (
        <div className={classes} onClick={() => {
            setSelected(id);
        }}>
            <p>{date}</p>
            <p>{time}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LineItem;


import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "../style/style.css";

function Header() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();

    function navigateToURL(url) {   
        navigate(url, {
            state: {
                id: location.state.id,
                auth: location.state.auth
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="header flex row">
            <div className="nav-wrap centered flex row">
                <h2 className="title" onClick={navigateToURL('/')}>Dashboard</h2>
                <div className="flex row right">
                    <p className="nav-item" onClick={navigateToURL('/')}>Create Entry</p>
                    <p className="nav-item" onClick={navigateToURL('/')}>Settings</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my onClick being called on render? - React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226076/why-is-my-onclick-being-called-on-render-react-js)

Comment: @David Yes, thank you. I needed to add `() => { }` to the onClick functions in `Header`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is being caused by how you have passed the *function* to `onClick`.

The `onClick` method expects a **callback function** which will be executed on the click event. As you have defined `onClick={navigateToURL('/')}`, this will execute navigateToURL('/') at the time of **event registration** itself and provide the **return value** of the function to the `onClick` as the ***callback function*** (which is not our intended case).

To prevent this, try writing it as: `onClick={() => navigateToURL('/')}`