# shown.bs.modal fires multiple times when you close and reopen modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made a fiddle illustrating the issue I am facing at the moment. So every time I close and open a modal, `shown.bs.modal` also fires multiple times. In this fiddle, every time you close and open a modal, number of alerts also increases (when it's supposed to trigger only once). http://jsfiddle.net/j36h2/1/

```
function openTestModal(){
    $('#testModal').modal({
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });

    $('#testModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        alert('');
    });
}

$('.testButton').click(function(){
    openTestModal();
});
```

Comment: place you `on` listener outside the function. What your basically saying here is, everytime you click the button, you listening for the modal. you only need to listen for it once

Comment: @ashley yup you are right :). my bad.

Comment: @pewpewlasers credits for the name ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click events firing multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times)

Comment: Make sure you only have Bootstrap's JS included once. I had a global load then in a script I had added `import { Modal } from "bootstrap";`, and inspecing to look for event listeners didn't reveal anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to extract your alert function out from your click event :

http://jsfiddle.net/SyCNj/2/

**extract :**

```
function openTestModal(){
    $('#testModal').modal({
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
}

$('#testModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
   alert('');
});

$('.testButton').click(function(){
    openTestModal();
});
```

Comment: There is also the jquery off function to do this, but it's just a bandage, your problem is well here, where your alert function is  written....

Comment: Why is it a bandage? its an available function, why not use it?

Answer (score 39):

or you can try this :

```
$('#testModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
 alert('');
 $(this).off('shown.bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: This is my preferred method.

Comment: Thank you for this solution

Answer (score 29):

The accepted answer from @Put12co22mer2 is correct. However, there are times when you want to rebind the event when opening the modal. Let's say you got some options that should be used.

```
function openTestModal(options){
    $('#testModal').modal({
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });

    $('#testModal').one('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // do something with options
        alert(options.foo);
    });
}

$('.testButton').click(function(){
    openTestModal({ foo: bar});
});
```

Then you can use `one` instead of `on`. The result will be the same as unbinding, but a bit cleaner in my opinion.

http://api.jquery.com/one/

> The  .one() method is identical to  .on(), except that the handler is
>   unbound after its first invocation

Comment: using one() was a cleaner solution for me than on()+off(), as my event binder is in a method that is called recursively.

Answer (score 7):

The function below is used for all the dialogs in my application.

It gets called each time with a different callback to execute. The easiest solution for me is simply to remove the event handler before adding a new one.

```
function messageBox(action,...) {               
    $("#modal-btn-ok").off("click");
    $("#modal-btn-ok").on("click", function(e) {
        action(e);
    });
```

Comment: this answer will resolve issue about double click on modal.
thanks anyway!

Comment: This solution is the easiest one. Tq.

Answer (score 4):

That's because your are attaching several event handlers for the event, at first click you are listening once, on the second click twice and so on, listen to the event outside the context of `openTestModal` function.

Answer (score 0):

Define variable and set it's value to 1; like:

```
function openTestModal(){
                $('#testModal').modal({
                    keyboard: false,
                    backdrop: 'static'
                });
               var e=1;
                $('#testModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    alert('');
                    e=0;
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following: (Bootstrap v3.3.6)

```
$('#dialog')
.modal({show: false})
.on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    //..................
}).on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
    //..................                  
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#dialog").off();
});
$('#dialog').modal('show');
```