# insert multiple records after calling ajax with bootrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm workong on ASP.NET CORE project. I use Bootstrap's modal in one view and call ajax to insert new record in database.  There's few inputs field, save and close buttion in bootstrap modal dialog. After first time I click save, the Bootstrap's modal will  disappear and a new record will be inserted in DB table. However, it will insert two records when I open the modal and click save again.

Moreover, it will insert three records if I open the modal to input and save again.

It seems it always keep reserve previous insert instance session. I have spent few hours working on it but still faild.

I appreciate your help and suggestion. Thanks.

FYI:

```
                     $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)                             

                     {
                         var modal = $(this);
                         modal.find('.modal-title').text('New Record');
              modal.find('#saveNewServiceRecord').click(function () {
                             _addActivity();

                         });
                     });


                     $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                         var modal = $(this);
                         modal.find('.modal-body input').val('');

                     });





                     function _addActivity() {
                         var data = {
                             ActivityDetails: $('#message-text').val(),
                             TicketID:      id                                                                       
                         };

                             $.ajax({
                                 url: "/Record/Create",
                                 type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                                 dataType: "json",
                                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                 success: function (result) {

                                     _getRecordList();
                                 },
                                 error: function(errormessage) {
                                     alert(errormessage.responseText);
                                 }
                             });
                         }
```

Comment: Check these posts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015719/shown-bs-modal-fires-multiple-times-when-you-close-and-reopen-modal  ----  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053874/bootstrap-3-3-2-modal-events-fire-multiple-times --- Looks like you're re-attaching the event right here `modal.find('#saveNewServiceRecord').click(function () {
                             _addActivity();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching the `click` event every time the `show.bs.modal` event is fired.

```
modal.find('#saveNewServiceRecord').click(function () {
     _addActivity();
}
```

You need to define this `click` event outside of the `show.bs.modal` event, or you can `unbind` it in the `hidden.bs.modal` event. I recommend using `on` and `off` for unbinding events.

Or use this below:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)  {
      var modal = $(this);
      modal.find('.modal-title').text('New Record');
})
.on('click', '#saveNewServiceRecord', function() {
    _addActivity()
});
function _addActivity() {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                                var modal = $(this);                            modal.find('.modal-title').text('New Record');                            $('#saveNewServiceRecord').on('click',function () {                                _addActivity();});});          $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                            var modal = $(this);
                            modal.find('.modal-body input').val('');
                            $('#saveNewServiceRecord').off('click');  });