# jQuery cloned element and it's child button click event fires multiple times

Tags: click, clone, jquery, duplication

I have some code to [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) a table row:

```
// Clone existing row and make it a template row
var clone = $('table tbody tr:last').clone();
clone.insertBefore('table tbody tr:first');
clone.find('.edit').click();
```

As you see I want to fire the `click` event of a `<button>` with class `.edit`.

The `click` event is like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit, .cancel', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do something here...
});
```

The user clicks a dialog's close button and then I remove the table's container with `$(".widget-container").remove();`. Later on this container can be recreated if the user opens the dialog again - if this happens the container and the table are once again inserted into the DOM.

This is the code I use to load the dialog and it's HTML:

```
 $.ajax({
         url: 'getDialogUrl',
         type: 'GET',
         cache: false,
         success: function(html)
         {
             $(html).insertAfter('.someOtherExistingDOMElement');

             ....
         }
```

The problem is that in this second time, when `clone.find('.edit').click();` is called it fires the `click` event twice. If I close the dialog and reopen it again, the click is fired 3 times and so on...

I thought that [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) would clear all events bound to the elements that got removed from the DOM. Looks like this is not happening.

I guess I'm cloning it wrongly. I tried `.clone(false)` and `.clone(false, false);` but it kept the same behavior.

Why is this happening? Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Can you show us your dialog opening script, i think i know the problem, but wont answer before being sure about it.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi need your entire function (including before, during and after that ajax call)

Comment: @LenielMacaferi actually, you could post you code here : http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @LenielMacaferi that was exactly what i though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was another instance of "Found the solution after posting the question"... this question helped me solve it:

[jQuery click events firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14969960/114029)

What I had to do whas this:

```
$('body').off().on('click', '.edit, .cancel', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do something here...
});
```

You see the `off()` there before the `on()`. This guarantees that only one `click` event is bound to the element.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969977/114029) sheds some light on the issue.

You see: each time the `on` event handler is run it attaches another handler for the element and that's why every time I closed/removed the dialog and then reopened/recreated it it would attach as many event handlers as the number of times the dialog was opened. :)