# Page becomes unresponsive after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with my jQuery/Javascript code. All works as expected but after some time the page becomes unresponsive throwing the `Unresponsive Script` error for jQuery.
I am using a [jQuery Library](https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster) for displaying lists as coverflow.

Also, after all calls to backend I have to refresh the particular div and hence I destroy and recreate the div every time the call is made to backend.

Please let me know what is the problem in the structure of the code given below:

(Please note this is just a snippet with important methods. All these methods also have other logic written in them which is not displayed here).

```js
function showAllData(dataFromServer) {
  $('#child').remove();
  $('#parent').append($('<div id="child"></div>'));

  $.each(dataFromServer.someArray, function(index, item) {
    var html = '<li>' + item + '</li>';
    $('#child').append($(html));
  });

  //Attach Event to div
  $("#child").on("click", function() {
    removeTag();
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  //got data from server(Spring MVC) in a var 'dataFromServer'
  //code not written here
  showAllData(dataFromServer);
  $("#child").flipster(); //a coverflow library 
});


$(document).on('submit', '#formSubmit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      dataFromClient: dataFromServer
    }),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      dataFromServer = data;
      showAllData(dataFromServer);
      $("#child").flipster();
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
  return false;
});

function removeTag() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'deleteBooks',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      keyword: tag,
      dataFromClient: dataFromServer
    }),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      dataFromServer = data;
      showAllData(dataFromServer);
      $("#child").flipster();
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
};
```

Any idea?

[EDIT]: This happens quickly when accessing website on mobile. The page freezes! But when working on desktop version, page becomes unresponsive after some time and error of `Maximum Call Stack Size Reached` error is thrown.

This can be because of the memory of smartphone. Nonetheless, problem is there in both versions.

Comment: the unresponsive script error usually occurs when you are trying to run a long loop in js. Try using some kind of lazy loading to shorten the number of loops. on scroll u can add more data on the fly.

Comment: @chrisgiffy All data is displayed within screen size. So no scrolling. Also, I do not have many loops and all those loops are kept in check to not go infinite. I am not sure about attaching event or something like that.

Comment: See: [Performance profiling with the Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline)

Comment: @Roberto I did look for it. But did not find any calls that are going in infinite loops.

Comment: I think @user978612 has done some good troubleshooting. Also see this question about using jQuery "off()" when adding a click handler: [jQuery click events firing multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times?rq=1)

Comment: I tried using unbind and the solution, but it still crashes in mobile web!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some recursion going on which is exponentially adding `#child` `.click()` handlers. I have made this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6gfohjp/2/) to simplify your code and demo what's going on. Open the console, click 'submit' to start, then click a few times on one of the list items. You'll see for each click, the console outputs more and more lines.

Try moving `$("#child").on("click"...){}` outside of `function showAllData(){}`

**Update**:
So that the handler works after you remove and re-add `#child` you can add the click listener like this:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '#child', function() {
    // 
});
```

I've put this in an updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6gfohjp/4/).

**Update 2**:
I saw that Flipster was not re-initialising after you refresh `#child` and came up with this:

Change `$("#child").flipster();` to `$("#parent").flipster();`. Then after doing `$('#child').remove()` in `showAllData()`:

```
// remove the flipster classes from #parent or flipster will not re-initialise when called next time.
$('#parent').removeClass('flipster').removeClass(function(index, css) {
    return (css.match(/(^|\s)flipster-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
```

I put this in a [codePen](http://codepen.io/lesleya/pen/qbQqmV/).

Comment: If I do that, it works well for the first time, but after my ajax calls, the event is not fired.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem ... good catch. Yet, why is the click handler added in showAllData() triggered immediately?  That is not obvious to me.

Comment: If I do what is suggested in this answer, its not triggered immediately. It is triggered when I click on the element. But after one ajax call, it is not fired anymore.

Comment: I may have simplified one step to far in the jsFiddle, by ignoring your remove/add of `#child`. I've updated the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6gfohjp/3/) and now when you click a list item, you can see it's calling `showAllData()` twice - once for the item click and once for the submit click... because you have _appended_ `#child` to `#submit`. Try using the `.after()` method instead:  `$('#parent').after($('<div id="child"></div>'));`

Comment: I do not know why but the event is not triggered after first time!

Comment: @Jagrut can you make a [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your current code on jsFiddle or codePen?

Comment: @Lesley I figured it out! The problem was with the plugin I was using. It was not unbinding the events even after I removed the elements it was applied on and even after I manually turn `off` all the events on that item. Do not know why was that happening. Maybe I need to look deeper in the plugin code. But for now, I settled with other plugin. Thanks a lot for your help. It did point me in the right direction!

Comment: @Jagrut Great! I was wondering whether it might be something to do with Flipster. I'm going to update my answer with another suggestion if you'd like to try - it might help if you wanted to stick with the Flipster plugin.

Comment: @Lesley Wow! Thanks for all the effort. It Worked! :)