# JavaScript array skipping values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that loops through all of the `<img>` tags and adds their source`src` into an array. When the user clicks on the main parent div, Bootstrap's modal fades in showing the rest of the gallery.

My problem is, whenever I press the right chevron on a specific div it shows the gallery and slides them perfectly but when I click on another div, the array skips two values and displays the third one instead.

To explain my problem more briefly, lets say I have this array:

`arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`

When I click the next button the first time it works perfectly

`1 => 2 => 3 => 4 => 5`

But when I click on another div and press next:

`1 => 2 => 5`

Here's a working [demo](http://jsbin.com/tisowacedi/edit?html,js,output) of what I have done till now.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 padBtm10">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" href="#" class="modal-trigger deco-none" onclick="return false;">
        <div class="card that_img radius10">
          <img data-caption-title="First caption" class="card-img-top img-responsive caption" src="http://dummyimage.com/500x300/000/fff" alt="Card image cap" />
          <span class="fa fa-search search fa-3x blue"></span>
          <div class="redbg radiusBtm10 white card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="imgs-album">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x300/000/fff" class="img-responsive full" data-caption-title="First caption for slider 1" />
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x300/ddd/fff" class="img-responsive full" data-caption-title="First caption for slider 2" />
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x300/aaa/fff" class="img-responsive full" data-caption-title="First caption for slider 3" />
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x300/ccc/000" class="img-responsive full" data-caption-title="First caption for slider 4" />
          </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

*update (HTML structure for the modal)*

```
<div class="modal breaker fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body noPad">
        <button type="button" class="close-pop close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div class="">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x right white"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;">
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x left white"></span>
            </a>
        </div>          
        <div class="pop-image">
            <img src="" class="img-responsive full">
        </div>
        <h4 class="modal_caption"></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var ready = function() {
    $(".that_img").hover(function() {
      $(this).find("span.search").css("display", "block");
    }, function() {
      $(this).find("span.search").css("display", "none");
    });

    $(".that_img").on({
      click: function() {
        var img_src_arr = $(this).find(".imgs-album")
          .children("img").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("src");
          }).get();

        var img_data_cap = $(this).find(".imgs-album")
          .children("img").map(function() {
            return $(this).data("caption-title");
          }).get();

        $(".pop-image").find("img").attr("src", img_src_arr[0]);
        $(".modal_caption").html(img_data_cap[0]);
        var counter = 0;
        counter >= 0 ? $(".left").hide() : $(".left").show();

        $(".right").on({
          click: function() {
            counter += 1;
            if (counter == 1) {
                $(".left").show()
            }
            var next = $(".pop-image").find("img")
              .attr("src", img_src_arr[counter]);
            var next_cap = $(".modal_caption")
              .html(img_data_cap[counter]);
            if (counter > (img_src_arr.length - 2)) {
              $(".right").hide();
              $(".left").show();
            }
          }
        });
        $(".left").on({
          click: function() {
            counter -= 1;
            $(".right").show();
            if (counter === 0) {
              $(".right").show();
              $(".left").hide();
            }
            $(".pop-image").find("img")
              .attr("src", img_src_arr[counter]);
            var prev = $(".modal_caption").html(img_data_cap[counter]);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(ready);
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because every time an image is clicked, click-handlers are added. With the first image everything seems fine because `.left` and `.right` have, at that point, a single click handler. Upon clicking another image, new click-handlers are added and now when you click a chevron, the 2 handlers are being executed resulting in your counter going up, or down, by 2 instead of 1. To prevent this from happening you will have to unbind the handlers from the object.

Change these lines, (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991189/2027280))

```
$(".right").on({
$(".left").on({
```

to,

```
$(".right").off().on({
$(".left").off().on({
```

And change this line,

```
counter >= 0 ? $(".left").hide() : $(".left").show();
```

to,

```
$(".right").show()
$(".left").hide()
```

Edit : as mentioned by juhana [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) is deprecated, so use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) instead.

Comment: As mentioned in the question you linked to, `.unbind()` is deprecated and `.off()` should be used instead.