# Click handler interferes with CSS hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On large screens, I want dropdowns to appear on hover, but on mobile I want to arrange them like accordions.

My jQuery is conflicting with my CSS.  On mobile, clicking the `li` creates all kinds of problems: the event fires over and over, and if I resize to larger viewport, the dropdown remains open and the `:focus` and `:hover` rules are disabled.

**Sass**

```
// If bigger screen, show the submenu on hover or focus
ul.sub {
  display: none;
}

body.desktop {
  li.dropdown:hover,
  li.dropdown:focus {
    > ul.sub {
      dispay: block;
    }
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
  if ($('body.desktop').length < 1) {
    $('li.dropdown > a').on('click', function(e){
      $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle('fast');
      e.preventDefault();
    });    
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `style="display:none;"` rule applied by the `.slideToggle()` method.  I needed to devise a way to override this on larger viewports.

JavaScript

```
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if (window.innerWidth > 795 ) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
  });
```

Then, to stop the event from firing again and again, [hat-tip to this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991189/1181150):

```
$("li.dropdown").unbind().click(function() { ... });
```