# How can I prevent my function to fire multiple times on one change?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".datepicker").on("change", function () {
      console.log("success");
  });
});
```

When I click on my `datepicker` in my console I get the following result:

```
success
success
success
```

I do not know why it is three time, but I need it only once.
So at the end of the function I put

```
$(this).unbind( "change" );
```

Now in my console the result is like expected:

```
success
```

But now, if I select the `datepicker` another time, then nothing is happening in the console.

The result I which is I want to be able to click the `datepicker` multiple times, but EACH time I click it, the console should show only ONCE:

```
success
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/982/

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: @j08691 ok, I will try to make one

Comment: after unbind you have to bind the event again, may be on focus

Comment: Listen for `input`, not `change`. Check the result; it might be that you assign too many handlers instead of just a single one.

Comment: instead of click event. Please use datepicker events methods

Comment: Might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/982/

Comment: Sound like you need debouncing. I couldn't find anything like officially / community accepted solution, but googling will lead you to many solutions. Also, event firing several times may be result of listener installed several times, so i want to recommend double-check you code, that happens often with ajax calls that insert raw html

Comment: @ganesh good idea

Comment: @ganesh worked very well.