# duplicate data when searching for a specific value in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to look for a specific value id in javascript object. I am getting duplicate objects.

This is the javascript code I am using:

```
$('.seat').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

   //SeatId is 1
    var categoryArray = jsonData;
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var ticketData, seatLocation;
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArray.length; i++) {
            var category = categoryArray[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < category.assignments.length; j++) {
                if (category.assignments[j].seatId == id) {
                    ticketData = category;
                    seatLocation = category.assignments[j];
                }
            }
        }

    console.log(ticketData);
    console.log(seatLocation);

});
```

This is how the objecs look like after being parsed:

[image]

And this is how the data is being printed:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `This is my JSON structure` - no it isn't ... JSON is  a string format, that's just a plain ol' javascript object

Comment: _"Everything is OK except the duplicate data I am getting"_ Which data are you referencing? What is expected result?

Comment: am I correct now? I edited my question.

Comment: You're using the same index `i` to access elements in both arrays `categoryArray[i].assignments[i]` you should probably use an inner loop to access the elements inside the `assignments` array.

Comment: @Titus I did. Still the same problem! Check out my code

Comment: Since you're `console.log`ing the results outside the loops the problem seems to be that you're click callback function is called more then once. Make sure you haven't added `purchase.js` more then once to the page.

Comment: It does appear your callback function is triggering more than once, take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$('.seat').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
                        var ticketData = [];
                    var seatLocation = [];
    //SeatId is 1
    var categoryArray = jsonData;
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.each(categoryArray, function (i, cat) {
        $.each(cat.assignments, function (j, ass) {
            if (ass.seatId == id) {
                    ticketData = cat;
                    seatLocation = ass;
                }
            });
    });

    console.log(ticketData);
    console.log(seatLocation);

});
```