# How to call jquery off method on a dynamic loaded button

Tags: jquery

I have the following click event that is being fired multiple times although I click only once

```
$(document).on('click', '#addToList', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     ...
 });
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times) you should use the `off` method e.g.

```
 $(element).off().on('click', function() {
     // function body
 });
```

however my jquery event is on the document since I load the control dynamically.

How do I add the `off` code to my event?

Comment: You must be associating multiple event handlers. Problem seems to be somewhere else. Can you show us How you are generating the element and attaching event handler?

Comment: @devc2 check my answer.. it will definitely help you.. even i had this same issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply reverse it first:

```
$(document)
    .off('click', '#addToList')
    .on('click', '#addToList', function() { ... })
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using

```
$(document).off('click', '#addToList').on('click', '#addToList', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Firstly removing the click binding event, through the off method, and chaining it onto an on click event, rebinding the function.