# jQuery AJAX call twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

It keeps calling ajax, on first time it works fine then on second time uploads 2 times the first time then the second time, on third call it uploads 3 times, it just keeps increasing and uploading older images.

```
      $(".imageUploadIcon").on('click', function(ev){
      var readyflag = true;
      if (readyflag == true){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var fd = new FormData();
          var imgid = $(this).data('img-id');
          $('#imgupload').click();
          var uid = <?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>;
          fd.append('uid', uid);
          fd.append('imgid', imgid);
        $("#imgupload").change(function (){
         var image = $('#imgupload')[0].files[0];
         fd.append('image',image);
        $("#img"+imgid).attr('src','img/loader.gif');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/usrIMG.php",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                  $("#img"+imgid).attr('src','../../'+data);
                  Materialize.toast('Image uploaded successfully!', 4000);
                  eadyflag = false;
                  imgid = '';
                  image = '';
                  $('#imgupload').val("");
              }
            });


      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click events firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're registering a new change handler on the `#imgupload` element, each time the `.imageUploadIcon` element is clicked.

You should be able to decouple your `$("#imgupload").change()` logic from you `.on('click', ..)` logic to resolve this issue.

The decoupling here means that you will need to send the `imgid` data from `.imageUploadIcon` to the `#imgupload` element. One way to do this might be to use jQuery's `.data()` method, as shown below:

```
$("#imgupload").change(function () {
    var image = $('#imgupload')[0].files[0];

    // Decouple the logic by exhanging 'imgid' via jQuery's data()
    // method. Here we are getting the 'imgid' that was set on 
    // #imgupload during .on('click',..)
    var imgid = $('#imgupload').data('imgid');

    var uid = <? php echo $_GET['user']; ?>;

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('uid', uid);
    fd.append('imgid', imgid);
    fd.append('image', image);

    $("#img" + imgid).attr('src', 'img/loader.gif');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/usrIMG.php",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#img" + imgid).attr('src', '../../' + data);
            Materialize.toast('Image uploaded successfully!', 4000);
            eadyflag = false;
            imgid = '';
            image = '';
            $('#imgupload').val("");
        }
    });
});


$(".imageUploadIcon").on('click', function (ev) {
    var readyflag = true;
    if (readyflag == true) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var imgid = $(this).data('img-id');

        // Set the imgid as custom data on #imgupload to decouple the 
        // logic the imgid can then be accessed in the #imgupload 
        // change() handler
        $('#imgupload').data('imgid', imgid)
        $('#imgupload').click();
    }
});
```

For more information on the jQuery's `.data()` method [see the documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you :)