# Table 'add' row is adding more than one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this table that adds a row, and it is adding the row; however, when I click a button to show where it adds the row (the current code), it's creating more than one row.

For example, if I click the button that loads the current page 3 times and then I click add row button, it adds 3 rows.

It is this method where it's looking for inputs that is causing the rows to add 3 times:

```
let inputs = $(this).parent().siblings().find("input[type='text']");
```

Would anyone know why it's doing this?

Thank you

```js
  var globalIndex  = 0;
  $(document).ready(function() {
        // create the original collection of student records.
        let arr1 = generateItem();
        if (arr1) {
        
          var tr;
          tr = $('<tr class="student-row">');
          tr.append("<td>" +"<button id='addBtn' type='button' class='btn btn-success addBtn' data-target='#addBtn' style='width:50px'>Add</button>" + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + ("<input type='text' class='form-control' style='width:50px' name='name' id='name'>") + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td>" + ("<input type='text' class='form-control' style='width:80px' name='email' id='email'>") + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + ("<input type='text' class='form-control' style='width:80px' name='phone' id='phone'>") + "</td>");
            
        $('#parentTableBody').append(tr);
        
          // clone that collection into a second array (?)
          let arr2 = [...arr1];
          
          // For each member of the student collection, create a table row.
          $.each(arr2, function(index, element) {
            // createRow() creates the DOM student row.
            let myRow = createRow(globalIndex, element);
            // Stick that row we just created into the parent table.
            $('#parentTableBody').append(myRow);
            // Add that student into the actual school info.
            // globalIndex++;
          });
        }
      


        /****
         * When the add button is clicked, we first create a new Student object.
         *  By doing this, we can then re-use the same createRow function we
         *  used when we created each initial row, thus ensuring the same result.
         ****/
        $("#addBtn").click(function() {
          // Get all the text input fields for this form.
          let inputs = $(this).parent().siblings().find("input[type='text']");
          // Create an empty student object.
          let myStudentObj = {};
          // Iterate over all the text inputs, and create properties for the student
          //  Each text input name will become the property name.
          inputs.each(function(index, input){
            /***
             * This is a complicated conversion: as the createRow has been defined to
             *  expect a Titlecase property (first letter is capitalized), but the input
             *  names are lower case, we need to retrieve the input name, convert it
             *  to all lowercase (just to be safe), then convert the first char to upper.
             ***/
            let propName = $(input).prop("name")
                                   .toLowerCase();
            propName = propName.replace(propName[0], propName[0].toUpperCase());
            // Now, create a property on the object with the proper value.
            myStudentObj[propName] = $(input).val();
            // And let's also blank that input field, so we can create a new student easily.
            $(input).val("");
          });
          
          /***
           * A little more funkiness: the index is the object's position in an array, or list.
           *   As we have been adding the records sequentially, the number of rows is the index
           *   of the last row. Adding one to that will give us the index of the current student.
           ***/
          let myStudentIndex = $("#parentTableBody tr.student-row").length,
              
          // And we can create that DOM fragment, as we did when we initialized the list above.
              myRow = createRow(myStudentIndex, myStudentObj);
          // add our newly created DOM fragment to the parent container.
          $("#parentTableBody").append(myRow);
          
          
      
        });
      
      
      });
      

      
      function generateItem() {
        var kids = [{
            Name: "Gina",
            Email: "gina@email.com",
            Phone: "211-456-1234",
            Edu: [{
                School: "college",
                Grade: "Freshmen",
                Job: "Student",
                Martial: "S",
                ETC: " "
              },
              {
                School: "college2",
                Grade: "Freshmen2",
                Job: "Student2",
                Martial: "S2",
                ETC: "2"
              },
              {
                School: "college3",
                Grade: "Freshmen3",
                Job: "Student3",
                Martial: "S3",
                ETC: "3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            Name: "Mark",
            Email: "mark@email.com",
            Phone: "144-411-2312",
            Edu: [{
              School: "highschool",
              Grade: "senior",
              Job: "cashier",
              Martial: "S",
              ETC: "honors"
            }]
          },
          {
            Name: "Jake",
            Email: "jake@email.com",
            Phone: "333-211-1111",
            Edu: [{
              School: "highschool",
              Grade: "junior",
              Job: "waiter",
              Martial: "S",
              ETC: "honors"
            }]
          }
        ];
        return kids;
      }
      /****
      * createRow() -- create the student row DOM fragment.
      * index = the student index
      * obj = the student object, formatted like:
      * obj = { Name: "name", Email: "email", Phone: "555-555-5555", <other optional fields>}
      *
      * returns a td DOM node containing the student info.
      ****/
      function createRow(index, obj) {
        // console.log(obj);
                  globalIndex++;
  
        tr = $('<tr class="student-row">');
        tr.append("<td>" + "<button id='modalBtn " + globalIndex + "' type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Info</button>" +
           "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (obj.Name || "") + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (obj.Email || "") + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (obj.Phone || "") + "</td>");
        return tr;
      }
```

```html
  
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
      <table id="parentTable">
        <thead>
          <tr class="category">
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      
        <tbody id="parentTableBody">
   
        </tbody>
      </table>
  
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h3>Info</h3>
      
              <div class="well well-sm overflow-auto">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="schoolTable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>School</th>
                      <th>Grade</th>
                      <th>Job</th>
                      <th>Martial</th>
                      <th>Etc</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="schoolModalBody">
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the step-by-step way to be able to reproduce the issue?
I wasn't able to reproduce what you said

Comment: Any chance you can slim down your code to only what's relevant? It's great to have a complete and verifiable example, but let's not forget the **M** in [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: `if I click the button that loads the current page 3 times and then I click add row button, it adds 3 rows.` - It sounds like your button that loads the current page attaches an additional event handler to the "Add Row" button each time.

Comment: @CalvinNunes I am sorry; I should have phrased the question better. But basically, there was a 'load button' that loads the 'code snippet' I included, and it adds row depending on how many 'load button' was clicked.

Comment: @TylerRoper I will make sure to keep that in mind in the future. I will slim down the code right now. Also, you are right. I did not realize it's adding an additional event handler because of the other buttons did not have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you describe the test scenario it looks like for each time you load the page, 1 more row is being added to the table. This could have to do with the following line of code:

```
$("#addBtn").click(function() { ... }
```

Everytime you load the page, another 'click' handler is added to your DOM element. This means the third time you load the page, 3 event hanlders are added. You should only add these event handlers once or remove all previous event handlers before adding another one. I found the best solution in a different post: [jQuery click events firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times)

```
$(".bet").unbind().click(function() {
    //Stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution; this was exactly what the problem was. I did not understood that 'click' handler was added to my DOM element every time I load the page. I will make sure to remove all previous event handlers before adding another one.