# DevExpress: sender.GetSelectedFieldValues not calling my client side call back

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I have a `GridExtension` for MVC that looks like this:

[image]

The table it gets data out of looks like this:

**Table Name: Category**

```
Id    Name
--------------
1     Foo
2     Bar
3     Gar
4     Har
```

When I select a row or more from the grid and click the **Delete** button on the top, I expect that my `DeleteSelectedCategories` handler should be called, which does happen.

However, in the `DeleteSelectedcategories` handler, when I call the `gvCategories.GetSelectedFieldValues` method supplying it the client side call back `DeleteCategories`, that method does not get called. Instead, I get all my script code shown in a message box like so:

[image]

I am using the almost the same code that is shown in [this example](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Selection/RowSelection) on the DevExpress documentation website.

Here's my code.

**View**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            WireHandlers();
        }
    );

        function DeleteCategories(selectedCategoriesArray) {

            debugger;

            if (selectedCategoriesArray.length == 0) return;

            for (var i = 0; i < selectedCategoriesArray.length; i++) {
                debugger;
            }
        }

        function DeleteSelectedCategories() {
            // debugger;

            if (gvCategories.GetSelectedRowCount() == 0) return;

            gvCategories.GetSelectedFieldValues('Id', DeleteCategories);
        }

        function WireHandlers() {
            $('#btnDeleteCategory').click(DeleteSelectedCategories);
        }
// ]]>
</script>

@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
@using System.Data;
@model IEnumerable<GlobalizationUI.BusinessObjects.Category>

@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "gvCategories";

        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Category", Action = "CategoriesPartial" };

        settings.Width = 1200;

        settings.SettingsPager.Position = PagerPosition.TopAndBottom;
        settings.SettingsPager.FirstPageButton.Visible = true;
        settings.SettingsPager.LastPageButton.Visible = true;
        settings.SettingsPager.PageSizeItemSettings.Visible = true;
        settings.SettingsPager.PageSizeItemSettings.Items = new string[] { "10", "20", "50", "100", "200" };
        settings.SettingsPager.PageSize = 50;

        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRowMenu = true;

        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ClearFilterButton.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowSelectCheckbox = true;

        settings.Settings.ShowHeaderFilterButton = true;

        settings.KeyFieldName = "Id";

        settings.Columns.Add("Name");

        settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Category", Action = "CreateNew" };
        settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Category", Action = "Edit" };

        settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.Inline;

        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.EditButton.Visible = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.UpdateButton.Visible = true;

    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

I am using DevExpress Extensions v12.2.10.0 for ASP.NET MVC 4 on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the GridView settings to a **separate** PartialView ([without any other tags](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9052)).

Comment: Thank you, @Mikhail. My callback is now being called. I read the article you linked to and you probably also replied on the DevExpress support forum to this query of mine.

However, now, both, the DeleteSelecteCategories method, which is the handler for my Delete button's click event, and consequently, the DeleteCategory method, which is called from within my DeleteSelectedCategories method, are being called twice.

Comment: Okay, that is a problem perhaps related to jQuery assigning an event listener twice. And I don't really know why it is doing that, but I found a solution to it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128163/jquery-single-button-click-click-event-firing-two-or-more-times

As far as the DevExpress bit was concerned, thank you, @Mikhail, you helped me solve it. It is solved now. Thank you.